# Calculate average time complexity (Big-O) for the code

Tags: java, big-o

can you pls help me to find the Big-O of the following code:

```
    /**
 * This will: 
 * 1) Remove duplicates from the give List and sort.
 * 2) find N-th largest element in the modified list and return the element.
 * @param listWithDup
 * @param index index of the largest element
 * @return
 */
public static int findElementbyIndex(List<Integer> listWithDup, int index){

  int toRet = 0, num = 0;
  TreeSet<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(listWithDup); // remove duplicates    and   sorts

  //        System.out.println("printing the sorted List:");
  //        for(int i: sortedSet){
  //            System.out.println(i);
  //        }
  Iterator<Integer> it = sortedSet.descendingIterator();

while(it.hasNext()){
  toRet = it.next();
  num++;
  if(num == index)
    break;
  }
  return toRet;     
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a.add(1);
    a.add(9);
    a.add(5);
    a.add(7);
    a.add(2);
    a.add(5);

    System.out.println("Expecting 7, because 7 is 2nd largest element in the modified list="+findElementbyIndex(a, 2));

}
```

The output I've got from this code is below:

```
printing the sorted List:
1
2
5
7
9
Expecting 7, because 7 is 2nd largest element in the modified list=7
```

I need to compute the average complexity of the findElementbyIndex() method.
Anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you think it is? People over here would be happy to correct your misconceptions or point you to the right direction, but that definitely requires some effort from your side first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TreeSet does a comparison based sort when you create it, so that will be O(n log n). The rest of your algorithm is a sequential search, so that is O(n), but since O(n log n) is a higher complexity your algorithm is O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

The best case, is the desired item is in the first index. The worst case is the desired item is in the last position. That means that the search will go through each item once, in the worst case. Therefore, with N inputs, the algorithm is O(N). :)